# How to run specific profile ID / suites (to run specific TestNG.xml) in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am new to Gradle, but I know in Maven we can run specific profile. 
In my case, I have 2 TestNG.xml files and in Maven *POM.xml* I can write like this

```xml
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>FirstRegression</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>SecondRegression</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

In command line , we can choose which profile (which TestNG.xml file) we want to run.
`mvn test -PFirstRegression` will execute our *testng1.xml* file only, meanwhile 
`mvn test -pSecondRegresion` will execute our *testng2.xml* file only.

How can we do this in *build.gradle* file ? so we can choose which profile to run in gradle.

I can put like this in build.gradle

```
plugins {
     id 'java'
 }

test {
     useTestNG() {
         suites 'testng1.xml'
         suites 'testng2.xml'
     }
 }
```

But when I run `gradle clean build` , it will run both of them.
Is there anyway we can say `gradle clean build --"please run testng2.xml only"` ?  Thank You.

Comment: what kind of framework are you using? because most of the time the frameworks have their own way of dealing the concept of profile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659986/maven-profiles-equivalent-of-gradle

Comment: https://coderanch.com/mobile/t/603665/similar-Maven-profile-Gradle

Comment: https://blog.gradle.org/maven-pom-profiles

Comment: @dsharew  , I am using TestNG framework. Thanks.