# Gradle control transitive from dependency build.gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm not sure if this is feasible, but wanted to get some comments/solution for the problem.

I'm creating a new dependency `com.example:app-dep:1.0.1` will be used in `com.example:app` as `compile` dependency.

`app-dep` having a dependency `io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.1.Final` which I don't want in `com.example:app` project, because I'm excluding the class file from `com.example:app-dep` related to `undertow` because the class requires on development time but not required in production.

When I add `com.example:app-dep:1.0.1` in `com.example:app` I want to exclude `io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.1.Final`.

> ***But I want to control that from `com.example:app-dep:1.0.1` maybe enable in future.***

**Some gradle I tried**

**TRY 1**

*app-dep - build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
  implementation('io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.1.Final') {
    transitive = true
  }
  implementation('io.undertow:undertow-servlet:2.0.1.Final') {
    transitive = false
  }
}
jar {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    excludes = ['com/example/ExampleServer**', 'public']
}
```

*production-app build.gradle*
using `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` bootRepackage

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.12.RELEASE"
  }
}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.example:app-dep:1.0.1'
}
```

OUTPUT: Still pulling and adding `io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.1.Final` in production spring-boot jar

**TRY 2**

Using profiles

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    if(isDev) {
        implementation 'io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.1.Final'
    }
}
```

OUTPUT: Class inside `app-dep` throwing compilation error saying the following when I do `./gradlew build`

> Undertow server = Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(8081,
>   "localhost").setHandler(routingHandler).build();
>                                 ^
>         symbol:   variable Undertow
>         location: class ExampleServer
>       26 errors

**What I can do but I don't want**

*In production-app build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
  compile('com.example:app-dep:1.0.1') {
    exclude(module: 'com.example.app-dep')
  }
}
```

Because I want to control that from `app-dep`

Comment: So far I understand you want to exclude dynamically but not to use `exclude` in your production project, right?.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean- the dependency `app-dep` is required at "development time" - does this mean you need this to run on a dev box but not in production- or is the dependency "compile-only"? In the first case, profiles could be used- in the second case, compileOnly should be enough (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph)

Comment: @JonathanJohx correct

Comment: Okay, then generally when you have a big project with several dependencies which should be excluded or included for `prod` and `dev` you should use `profiles` for dependencies, then if it is `prod` you can add/exclude, perhaps this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40660106/10426557 can help you.

Comment: @JonathanJohx I tried that no luck, added the output in the question `TRY 2`