# Is it possible to activate and deactivate Gradle projects similarly to Maven modules via profiles?

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea

The application landscape consists of several domains with dozens of projects (Maven modules) which can be turned on or off via simple mouse clicks in IntelliJ IDEA.
This is how these modules are defined via profiles in Maven:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>at.wrwks.pipe</groupId>
  <artifactId>pipe.reactor.blue</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>modules-blueops</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <modules>
        <module>../../blueops/blueops.reactor</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
...
```

[image: This is how such a module can be activated via a checkbox in IntelliJ IDEA]

How can this be achieved with Gradle also in IDEA? I haven't found a profile-equivalent in Gradle yet, using if/else in the build script is cumbersome and there is no UI support for such custom steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven profiles equivalent of Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659986/maven-profiles-equivalent-of-gradle)

Comment: Have you seen [Migrating Maven profiles and properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:profiles_and_properties) already?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Yes, I read those, but they don't cover my use case, just a few environment-specific profiles - I have dozens of modules which can be turned on or off via the UI in IDEA.